# How to save my project to jpg?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, save, drawrectangle

I made a simple project, when I insert the height and width of the program can make a rectangles like a chessboard model and I want to save it to jpg how to do?
Please...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DrawingTest3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Graphics drawArea;


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            drawArea = drawingArea.CreateGraphics();
        }

        private void btDraw_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int panjang = Convert.ToInt32(tbPanjang.Text);
            int lebar = Convert.ToInt32(tbLebar.Text);

            drawArea.Clear(Color.White);

            Pen blackPen = new Pen(Color.Black);

            drawArea.DrawRectangle(blackPen, 0, 624, 40, 40);


            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                drawArea.DrawRectangle(blackPen, 250, 10 + (lebar * i), panjang, lebar);
                drawArea.DrawRectangle(blackPen, 250 + (panjang), 10 + (lebar * i), panjang, lebar);
                drawArea.DrawRectangle(blackPen, 250 + (2 * panjang), 10 + (lebar * i), panjang, lebar);
                drawArea.DrawRectangle(blackPen, 250 + (3 * panjang), 10 + (lebar * i), panjang, lebar);
                drawArea.DrawRectangle(blackPen, 250 + (4 * panjang), 10 + (lebar * i), panjang, lebar);
                drawArea.DrawRectangle(blackPen, 250 + (5 * panjang), 10 + (lebar * i), panjang, lebar);
                drawArea.DrawRectangle(blackPen, 250 + (6 * panjang), 10 + (lebar * i), panjang, lebar);
                drawArea.DrawRectangle(blackPen, 250 + (7 * panjang), 10 + (lebar * i), panjang, lebar);
                drawArea.DrawRectangle(blackPen, 250 + (8 * panjang), 10 + (lebar * i), panjang, lebar);
                drawArea.DrawRectangle(blackPen, 250 + (9 * panjang), 10 + (lebar * i), panjang, lebar);
            }

        }

    }
}
```

What should be added and replaced?

Comment: Save it as bitmap instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an in-memory bitmap, draw your rectangles and then save it

```
using (var drawingArea = new Bitmap(width, height))
{
   ... draw the rectangles
   drawingArea.Save(filename, ImageFormat.Jpeg); // or Bmp or Gif
}
```